# Multiple initialization for page object and log4j in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, log4j

i have 2 test written in page factory(in 1 class without main method) with 3 pages class.
I have question about multiple page objects and Log4j initialization (for each test case), can I initialize it globally for all tests? Or it must be initialized one time per each test case in @Test?

Comment: I depends on the situation.  If you are going to be performing a series of tests in sequence and you control the sequence, then you can declare the page object at the class level, but it is probably a better, safe practice to initialize the page object at each test method.  Sometimes a page object needs to be re-created within the same test, again, depends on the test scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It should be initialized per each test.

Initialization of Page Factory means "Find all annotated elements and assign references".

The key point is ivoking the `PageFactory` `initElements` method like this:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, MyClass.class);
```

Or you can hide it in a class constructor like this:

```
public class MyClass {

@FindBy(id = "foo")
private WebElement fooElement;

@FindBy(id = "bar")
private WebElement barElement

public MyClass(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

The method `initElements` runs `findElement` or `findElements` methods of `WebDriver` and finds all elements annotated with `@FindBy`. So when you use the element, it's already found or exception is thrown, but only during the use of the element.

If you would try to initialize your class globally, you would get a lot of errors like `NoSuchElementException` because initializer would not be able to find elements for all tests on one page. Even if it did, you would still get `StaleElementReferenceException` because page maybe looks the same for all the tests, but references are completely different.